# Batery is above 12 volts but car ignition fades

Tags: battery, starter

I've got this car that does not start and seems like a battery problem at first, when you turn the key it doesn't turn on and it sounds like the battery is fading, but when i chek the voltage it show above 12 volts, so the battery seems to be ok, I checked the starter voltage and it shows above 11 volts, it starts if you charge it with another car connected to it, I've been told it's the starter the cause, how can I be sure if is one thing or the other.

Lately I've got some trouble with the battery discharging because a ligth problem and I disconected it a couple of times but it worked just fine when reconected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get the battery load tested. It may be the right voltage but not be putting out enough current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the battery shows > 12 volts, it does not reliably mean that the battery is not the issue. How old is the battery? If > 4 years, it's probably time to replace it.

It sounds like your car is not putting out enough Cold Crank Amps (CCA). There are two things you should do to eliminate the battery being the issue:

1. Put the battery on a load tester and check the amps
2. Replace the battery temporarily (e.g. jump start pack with the battery terminals removed)